# Cannot set WH_KEYBOARD hook. WH_KEYBOARD_LL works

Tags: winapi

This is the WH_KEYBOARD_LL code which works for me.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

HHOOK _hook;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;
LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    cout << nCode;
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void SetHook() {
    if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0))) {
        cout << "SetWindowsHookEx Fail";
    }
}

void ReleaseHook() {
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hook);
}

int main() {
    SetHook();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        // do something here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However when I change the SetWindowsHookEx line to `if (!(_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, HookCallback, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId())))`, it does not work.

I have 3 questions.

1. How do I get `WH_KEYBOARD` hook to work?
2. If I replace the comment inside the loop, with a `cout`, I don't see any console output. So I am confused, does the body of the loop execute at all?
3. I also read that inside the loop of `GetMessage`, I should add a call to `DispatchMessage`. What's the difference between `DispatchMessage` and `CallNextHookEx`? I read the docs about both of them, but couldn't understand.

Comment: Both [C] and [C++] tags are okay, but you would get more windows geeks into the thread if you'd put [winapi]

Comment: IMO, you should *only* tag with the language you're actually using, which in this case is C++. Additionally, in C++ you should use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. I'd also recommend you to use [the initializer-if statement](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0305r0.html) (available since MSVC 14.11), to make your `SetHook()` function easier to read. [`using namespace std;` is also a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and you should never use it.

Comment: PS: "An error may occur if the hMod parameter is NULL and the dwThreadId parameter is zero"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) never returns because without window handle associated with the process there is no associated message queue and no message processing magic happens (unless you post messages manually). This is insane, but I guess it explains the name of the operating system. Quote from [`GetMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The GetMessage function retrieves messages associated with the window
>   identified by the hWnd parameter or any of its children

You get `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` to work because it  is called regardless `GetMessage()`. You don't get calls to `WH_KEYBOARD` hook because it is called only if `GetMessage()` is functioning.

Quote from [Hooks Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959(v=vs.85).aspx#wh_keyboard_llhook):

> **WH_KEYBOARD_LL**
>
> The WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook enables you to monitor keyboard input events
>   **about to be posted in a thread input queue**. For more information, see
>   the LowLevelKeyboardProc callback function.
>
> **WH_KEYBOARD**
>
> The WH_KEYBOARD hook enables an application to monitor message traffic
>   for WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP messages **about to be returned by the
>   GetMessage or PeekMessage function**. You can use the WH_KEYBOARD hook
>   to monitor keyboard **input posted to a message queue**.

Q&A:

> How do I get WH_KEYBOARD hook to work?

You need to create a window. Even message box will do. Even hidden.

> If I replace the comment inside the loop, with a cout, I don't see any console output. So I am confused, does the body of the loop
>   execute at all?

No. Because `GetMessage()` blocks forever. Because there are no incoming messages.

> I also read that inside the loop of GetMessage, I should add a call to DispatchMessage. What's the difference between DispatchMessage and CallNextHookEx? I read the docs about both of them, but couldn't understand.

These two functionalities are orthogonal.

After you removed the message from the queue with `GetMessage()` you need to call [`DispatchMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934(v=vs.85).aspx) to pass the message to [`WindowProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) associated with the window. Otherwise `WindowProc` with not receive it.

[`CallNextHookEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974(v=vs.85).aspx) passes message to the next hook in the chain if there are several hooks installed.

<sub>**Additionally:**</sub>

<sub>(1) You should not pass `_hook` into `CallNextHookEx`. The first parameter is ignored anyway. Passing hook handle is just confusing.</sub>

<sub>(2) You should always implement proper error checking.</sub>

<sub>(3) Don't forget to unhook the hook.</sub>

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean to say that for the `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` program, it would work even if I remove the call to `GetMessage()`? Because I tried removing the `GetMessage()` and it stopped getting the messages.

Comment: @vicky Yes that's what I meant. I cannot tell for sure what's happening without seeing the code, but you cannot "remove call" to `GetMessage()`, because you need to fill the loop with something. If you just run `while(true);` it will consume all the CPU time of this thread and there may be no room for the hook to run. So instead you could try to `Sleep()` the thread or to yield resources any other way to see if hook works. Alternatively, I think it is possible to bind the hook  to a different thread.

Comment: You have to have a message loop in order to receive the hook messages.  The callback function is called from GetMessage().

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think a hidden window will solve the OPs problem.  I might be mistaken, but AFAIK you can't give a hidden window the keyboard focus.  Also, I'm pretty sure the only reason the OP needs a window at all is that they're only hooking their own process, obviously a keyboard hook won't trigger if there are no keyboard events for the process(es) being monitored.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [`KeyboardProc` callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984.aspx) documentation:

> An application-defined or library-defined callback function used with the `SetWindowsHookEx` function. **The system calls this function whenever an application calls the `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` function and there is a keyboard message (`WM_KEYUP` or `WM_KEYDOWN`) to be processed**.

Your `WH_KEYBOARD` callback does not work because the thread that is hooked is calling `GetMessage()` but is not receiving any `WM_KEYUP` or `WM_KEYDOWN` messages. Those are window messages, but you have no visual window for them to be posted to.

A `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook operates at a lower level and so it does not require the hooked thread to call `(Get|Peek)Message()` to receive window messages. Per the [`LowLevelKeyboardProc` callback function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) documentation:

> An application-defined or library-defined callback function used with the `SetWindowsHookEx` function. **The system calls this function every time a new keyboard input event is about to be posted into a thread input queue.**